# How to Avoid Constructor calling During Object Creation?

Tags: java

I want to avoid the constructor calling during object creation in java (either default constructor or user defined constructor) . Is it possible to avoid constructor calling during object creation???

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Can you give a little more background? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Simple answer: No, it's not possible.

Comment: do you want to prevent users of your class to do `new MyClass()` and/or `new MyClass(args...)` ? is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply extract the intialization logic that you want to avoid into another method called init. You can not avoid calling exactly one constructor.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what pattern or strategy you use, at some point your will need to call a constructor if you want to create an object.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, its possible under some circumstances by using classes from the JVM implementation (which do not belong to the JRE API and are implemenation specific).

One example here http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue175.html

It should also be possible using sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance() (Java7)

Also, the constructor is apparently bypassed when using the clone()-method to create a copy of an object (and the class doesn't override clone to implement it different from the Object.clone() method).

All of these possibilities come with strings attached and should be used carefully, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the constructors of a class. They will still be called, but not executed. For example, the following JUnit+JMockit test does that:

```
static class CodeUnderTest
{
    private final SomeDependency someDep = new SomeDependency(123, "abc");

    int doSomething(String s)
    {
        someDep.doSomethingElse(s);
        return someDep.getValue(); 
    }
}

static final class SomeDependency
{
    SomeDependency(int i, String s) { throw new RuntimeException("won't run"); }
    int getValue() { return -1; }
}

@Test
public void mockEntireClassIncludingItsConstructors()
{
    new NonStrictExpectations() {
        @Mocked SomeDependency mockDep;
        { mockDep.getValue(); result = 123; }
    };

    int result = new CodeUnderTest().doSomething("testing");

    assertEquals(123, result);
}
```